# Kingsway Soft Data Migration - Entitlement entity error with Status

Tags: dynamics-crm, database-migration, entitlements, kingswaysoft

I have to migrate entitlements records from On-premise to an online environment. While moving using Kingsway soft, I am getting below error when I am trying to move entitlement with Status -

**CRM service call returned an error: You can't set an entitlement to the Expired state when it is in draft state. Active entitlements automatically expire when their end date passes.**

If I just move entitlement record without status, then entitlement record is getting created in Draft status and I am again getting the same error while updating it's status.

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like the entitlement entity is a time-sensitive one, the state will transit automatically. If this is the case, the entity is unlikely to have a good migration story. Audit entity is another example of such problem (although the behaviors are quite different).

Answer (score 0):

Entitlements are asynchronous jobs - copy them as 'Draft' the online service will expire them after end date passes (as the error tells you)